# Can we override a core plugin

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

I want to override a core plugin in `Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin` -> `Authentication.php`

Is this even possible to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise againts overriding the plugin, but adding your own plugin to that plugin and do your customisation that way. This way you avoid future errors.

Comment: How will  we achieve it ?

Comment: The same way as @RK Rathod has but without disabling the core plugin.Just add your own plugin to `Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication`

Answer (score 3):

**After disable core plugin you can override**

> **Vender\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication">
        <plugin name="authentication" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="vender_module_authentication" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication" sortOrder="60" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```